# Sharing code across test targets when using the Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have some code that I need to share across test targets, while I'm using the Swift Package Manager. To do this, I have a .testTarget that I also name as a dependency in another .testTarget.

Here is a simple example:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ExampleLib",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "ExampleLib",
            targets: ["ExampleLib"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "ExampleLib",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Common",
            dependencies: ["ExampleLib"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ExampleLibTests",
            dependencies: ["Common"]),
            
    ]
)
```

If I try to build this package in Xcode, I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile (The workspace has a reference to a missing target with GUID 'PACKAGE-TARGET:Common')
```

However, if I build from the command line (`swift build`) or test from the command line (`swift test`), I get success.

I'm using Xcode 12 beta 6, but have also tried Xcode 11.5 (with a change to the Package.swift header) and get the same results.

Here is the complete Swift package example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6ypvbfonnb2zyk/ExampleLib.zip?dl=0

I really would like to use this in Xcode to build for iOS. Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the same issue and solved it by defining a **Target** (not Test Target) instead for `Common`.

My `Package.swift` file:

```swift
// ...
.target(name: "Common", dependencies: ["App"], path: "Tests/Common"),
.testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App", "Common"]),
.testTarget(name: "IntegrationTests", dependencies: ["App", "Common"])
// ...
```

Comment: Rock'n! Thanks! It works! I'm assuming this not behavior as intended, and is a work around?

Comment: A good solution +50

Comment: This is a good solution unless you actually need to use @testsble imports to uplift access levels, which is only available inside .testTarget().